# Connecting to a websocket, headers must be strings and dictionaries at the same time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, websocket

I am trying to scrape a web page that has a websocket connection by connecting to the webscoket myself. This is my code:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

headers = json.dumps({
'Connection': 'Upgrade',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Upgrade': 'websocket',
'Origin': 'https://www.bet777.be',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version': 13,
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'es,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,es-AR;q=0.7',
'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'mYc+hqhy8sUyeilrxyxSPA==',
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; 
client_max_window_bits',
})
ws = create_connection('wss://pushserver- 
uk.sbtech.com/signalr/connecttransport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=nOugyCC54kCePwbLVXCfkfpxZsipI83mU476SdYNspEAD2U0%2F3O44lja67ujJErljZiflHtWyOwELt0OHfQhBQxXu14hVe8zE%2Fr4syolXWBCWWoG%2B2D8WwmUCxi5HSUz4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=9', header=headers)

ws.send('''{"H":"communicationhub","I":0,"M":"Introduce"}''')
while True:
    print(ws.recv)
```

I get the the folloing error:

```
File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 124, in _get_handshake_headers
key = options['header']['Sec-WebSocket-Key']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And if I delete the Sec-WebScoket-Key part i get a 400 status response.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: using a dict instead of json.dump gets me the following error.
 File 
"/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/sitepackages/websocket/_handshake.py", 
line 139, in 
    if v is not None

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Comment: How is this error message related to your code?

Answer (score 0):

The `header` parameter of `websocket.create_connection` should be a dict, rather than a JSON string, so instead of using `json.dumps` to convert the dict to a string, pass the dict directly as headers:

```
headers = {
    'Connection': 'Upgrade',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade': 'websocket',
    'Origin': 'https://www.bet777.be',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'es,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,es-AR;q=0.7',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'mYc+hqhy8sUyeilrxyxSPA==',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
}
ws = create_connection('wss://pushserver-uk.sbtech.com/signalr/connecttransport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=nOugyCC54kCePwbLVXCfkfpxZsipI83mU476SdYNspEAD2U0%2F3O44lja67ujJErljZiflHtWyOwELt0OHfQhBQxXu14hVe8zE%2Fr4syolXWBCWWoG%2B2D8WwmUCxi5HSUz4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22communicationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=9',
    header=headers)
```

Comment: I got the following error:  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 139, in <listcomp>
    if v is not None
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Header values have to be all strings, so you should quote the `13` you set for the key `'Sec-WebSocket-Version'` instead. I've updated my answer accordingly.